# Fork lube. Should I use it? If so how often?

Tags: mountain-bike, mechanical, lubricant, fork, suspension

I ride a mountain bike with front suspension. I've recently seen fork lube for sale on an online retailer. This got me thinking. Do I need to be using fork lube? How does it help? If I bought some how often do I need to use it and how do I apply it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consult the repair manual for your fork. It will tell you where to lubricate and how much to apply. Without knowing what fork you have, we can others only speculate. Check the manual or post the model and we can look at it.

Comment: Damn. I was hoping there were some general rules that could be followed. You're right, my Forks are RockShox Recons air and they provide some tips http://www.sram.com/en/service/rockshox/tuning_tips.php#DosAndDonts

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because I think whatsisname is right. There are no general rules, it's probably different for every type of fork

Answer (score 2):

I have not looked into this but my first inclination is to avoid it.  Your fork already has oil on the inside and seals that are supposed to keep elements on the outside.  So, for this lube to make much of a difference it would have to soak into the seals, which means the seals aren't that sealed!

I would also think that putting lube on the stanchions would attact grit and grime, something I work hard at keeping away from them.

If your fork is sticking or otherwise not moving smoothly through it's travel, you may want to look into getting it rebuilt.

Just my two cents.

Comment: This has been my inclination for the last 10 years or so... My forks have always performed flawlessly without lube, just the occasional (every couple of years) rebuild